# Error: error:0606508A:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length

Tags: php, node.js, encryption

Could someone please take a look at my code and the following error? I cant figure out the solution after hours of searching.

````
const decrypt = (textBase64, keyBase64, ivBase64) => {
  const algorithm = "AES-256-CBC";
  const ivBuffer = Buffer.from(ivBase64, "base64");
  const keyBuffer = Buffer.from(keyBase64, "base64");

  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, keyBuffer, ivBuffer);
  decipher.setAutoPadding(false);

  let decrypted = decipher.update(textBase64, "base64", "utf8");
  decrypted += decipher.final("utf8");
  return decrypted;
};

const encryptedMessage =
  "eVlXaWgxTWw1Wm1paStNckh0cy9IMFhjSnZTTzlBMm9BWnB3SS8vcjYyTT0=";
const key = "wu6eAo3MA4XM2G2vszNrppGJb+T/Wgv+TwUmOA6bAl8=";
const iv = Buffer.from(
  "ORpU3E8fsbTP8drytjP9yDIq7DT9SmNIEUQIdKWV81NbpTi8",
  "base64"
).slice(0, 16);

// the message comes from the bytes AFTER the IV - this is what you should decrypt
const message = Buffer.from(encryptedMessage, "base64").slice(16);

const result = decrypt(message, key, iv);

res.send("Decrypted: " + result);```
````

Comment: Please add how you interpret `data not multiple of block length`. What data would that refer to, what is its length, what is the *block length*?

Comment: Im sorry, I dont exactly understand what you mean. But there is a php script that encrypts a string. It encrypts it with the key and IV, which I'm trying to decrypt.

The message I'd like to decrypt is the const encryptedMessage.